# How to trace a raw (character) device stream on Unix?

Tags: unix, daemon

I'm trying to trace what is transiting in a raw (character) device on an Unix system (ex: `/dev/tty.baseband`) for DEBUG purpose.

I am thinking of creating a deamon that would:

- upon start rename `/dev/tty.baseband` to `/dev/tty.baseband.old`.
- create a raw node `/dev/tty.baseband`
- spawn two threads:
- Thread 1: reading `/dev/tty.baseband.old` writing into `/dev/tty.baseband`
- Thread 2: reading  `/dev/tty.baseband` writing into `/dev/tty.baseband.old`

This would work a little bit like a MITM process. I wonder if there is not a 'standard' way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I found how to do it. The way to go was to:

- create a process
- create a new pseudo-terminal, opening /dev/ptmx
- call grantpt and unlockpt on the slave
- rename the terminal to intecept
- rename the terminal create the the previous name of the intecepted terminal

I wrote a small article and provided the source code if anyone need it:

http://fabiensanglard.net/cellphoneModem/index2.php